# How to remove duplicate items from a list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to remove the duplicate words from the text file and write a new file. I am first sorting W1.txt
and then trying to remove the duplicate words and putting them inside a new text file called W1.txt.

However my code is getting stuck and there is no output. There was no debug error.

```
with open("W1.txt") as f2:
         W = sorted(word.strip(",") for line in f2 for word in line.split())
    
    newList = []
    for item in W:
        unique = True
        current = W.pop()  
    
    for string in W:
        if current in string:
           unique = False
    
        if unique:
           newList.append(current)  
    
           W.insert(0, current)
         
    with open('W.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
         for listitem in newList:
             filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
```

Comment: use a dict and check if a word is in there or not.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: if you want to keep the method you have with assigning a unique variable here is the code:

ALSO BE CAREFUL WITH YOUR INDENTATION. The line after the with statement has 4 spaces/1 tab and after you are done opening the file, the next line has no indents. Same with for loops and if statements, after you're done with the loop or condition remove the indent for the next line.

```
with open("W1.txt") as f2:
    W = sorted(word.strip(",") for line in f2 for word in line.split())
    
newList = []
for item in W:
    unique = True
    current = W.pop()
    
    # you want to check if the current item is in newList not if it exists in W
    if current in newList:
        unique = False
    
    if unique:
        newList.append(current)  
    
        W.insert(0, current)
         
         
with open('W.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
    for listitem in newList:
        filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
```

Your second loop is running infinitely since you keep adding to it with the W.insert() function.

If you want to use loops, use the first bit of code:

What you want to do is check if the item is already in your newList. If it is then you skip it, if it isn't then you add to it.

Something like this:

```
with open("W1.txt") as f2:
    W = sorted(word.strip(",") for line in f2 for word in line.split())
    
newList = []
for item in W:
    # check if the item that you are looping through is already in your list
    if item in newList:
        # if the item exists then skip to the next item
        continue
    else:
        # the item is not in your list so add it in
        newList.append(item)
    
with open('W.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
    for listitem in newList:
        filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
```

If you want a quicker way of doing this, there is an inbuilt function called set which removes all duplicates and returns a tuple:

```
with open("W1.txt") as f2:
    W = sorted(word.strip(",") for line in f2 for word in line.split())
    
remove_duplicates = set(W)
newList = list(remove_duplicates) # set returns a tuple and if you want a list use this

with open('W.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
    for listitem in newList:
        filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new to Python and this is really helpful.